# Android and IOS Calc() tag problems

Tags: css, css-calc

Hello I have problems with the Calc() tag on both Safari for IOS and the standard Android browser.

The site got a fixed width and height unless the Calc() tag is supported.

Chrome -> Calc supported no problem
Safari Mac -> Calc not supported fixed wide and height no problem
Safari IOS -> Calc supported does not display properly!

Example site: http://www.aquatest.nl

Calc compatibility chart: http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

I had to use the viewport tag to set an fixed width and height to disable the automatic resizing which occurs on mobile browsers.